# My bottom border won't move past a certain point?

Tags: css

I use weebly as a website editor but am editing the code to get it to how I like it... I am trying to get a bottom border around my section and the top one worked but when I use the bottom border it goes to the bottom of the page...

I've tried using margin and padding both did not work and only moved the border up to a certain point that was not high enough.

With weebly, the html is not normal looking as it does not hold all of the information and text and tags because it is from a template (I assume) so I don't think I am able to paste the html since it won't be of any help...

I am new to coding and new to CSS so if i am not informative enough i'm sorry!

Here's the CSS code that includes my top border..

```
.content-wrap {
    padding: 5px, 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 7px solid rgb(129,130,133);
    border-bottom: 7px solid rgb(129,130,133);
}
```

Hopefully someone can help with this amount of information.. Thanks in advance

HTML, if you need more let me know...

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
      <div id="weebly-area-24" class="weebly-area wsite-elements wsite-not-footer wsite-platform-area">
    <ul id="weebly-area-24" class="weebly-content-area ">

</ul>
</div><div id="secondlist" class="weebly-area wsite-elements  wsite-not-footer">
    <div class="wsite-section-wrap" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="wsite-section wsite-body-section wsite-section-bg-image wsite-background-section-49 wsite-custom-background ui-resizable" style="height: 411px; background-position: 50% 42.87%; background-size: cover !important; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: transparent; background-image: url(&quot;/uploads/3/4/5/0/34502789/background-images/452911764.jpg&quot;);" data-section="49">
```

Comment: The HTML as well as more CSS, would be a lot of help

Comment: This isn't your issue, but your `padding` value is incorrect - you can't have commas. It should just be `padding: 5px;`. We can't really help out beyond guessing if you don't reproduce the problem for us. We need a [mcve] that verifiably reproduces the problem.

Comment: The way you wrote that rule for `padding` with a comma between values, it's not gonna provide any padding to the `.content-wrap` box.

Comment: Okay I removed the padding altogether so it's at "padding: none;" to see what it would do and it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

You should use margin-bottom:5px. This will move the bottom border and you can adjust based on how far you want the bottom border to move.

The reason margin: 5px, 5px or padding: 5px, 5px will not work is due to the comma in between the values

Comment: Oh that makes sense! But I guess padding isn't what I want anyways because It isn't moving the bottom border up at all, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes i believe you are looking for margin-bottom:5px I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Would you be able to mark as solved if this helped you fix your issue?

Comment: I fixed the padding comma issue and entered the margin-bottom property but still not helping to move the border up...

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: I could try to see the issue for you if your site is live on a test url

Comment: it's not live, it's on edit mode.... heres the link though.. not sure if it will work.... https://34502789-654189249783109926.preview.editmysite.com/editor/preview.php ..... i could screenshot it but not sure how i'd get the picture to you??

Comment: If you are using chrome, you can right click the element and click inspect, from here your html and css will pop up on the side, you can locate your section for which you wish to add your border.  You can hover over the html in the right hand panel until you locate the correct section.  Let me know what the class is of the html element that you are trying to add the border to. It is possible we are trying to add the border to the wrong class in our css.

Comment: the div class is "content-wrap" .... on the inspector window it looks like this:
<div class="content-wrap"> == $0

Comment: If you would like to post only that section of html I can see if I would be able to assist more.